# Breathing problems or lack of training

Tags: voice, breathing

I started singing again after many years and I noticed that when I sing and breath, I feel so tense in my throat at the same time. I breath from abdomen, but I feel so tense in my chest and throat area too. I have a vocal range of F3-C6, when I trained many years ago I could reach all those notes with no issue, now I feel like I'm killing my voice and it becomes lazy with no energy after a while. I am training to be a professional singer now, and I really want to get rid of this problem.
I also have a lot of air in my voice.

Comment: By no means scientific, but... I find I really lose it if I don't sing for 6 months to a year, & it will take me 6 - 8 weeks to get it back again. First week I think I can do it, 2nd week I'm a failure, after that it starts to regain power.  [I've been singing for 45 years, with breaks]

Comment: Thank you for that. Yeah after 8 years of not singing I guess so. Let me see how I feel in 2 months from now. I should be able to hit a C6 with no problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you re-training your body as you re-train your voice?

You mentioned breathing from your abs, are you Supporting that breath? standing tall, feet shoulder width apart, shoulders rolled down and back, with the tummy tucked in pulling the navel to the spine... if you start to feel tense- move- move your neck, do some shoulder rolls and arm swings.

Get back in the swing of doing theatre style full body warm ups along with your vocal warm ups. Refocus your general exercise around core strengthening (all your power is in your core) think Pilates, with a bit of cardio for endurance, like Zumba (core focused cardio).

What you described sounds like the vocal version of trying to open a jar with your wrists. It starts to hurt real quick. When we stop, shake it out, breathe and use All the muscles in our Backs, that jar opens no problem. We only need to Tap into our Power.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to check back on this.
May as well reply.
I am now a pro singer, recording and releasing my is, working with producers.
My voice has gotten a lot better, still a tad insecure, but a whole lot better.

Comment: Glad things have worked out. Please edit your original post and add these comments there, rather than as an answer to that question. It would also be very good to know whether the answers you got here were helpful to you.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/70261)

Answer (score 0):

As you are training to be a professional singer, you will be regularly meeting with a good teacher.  Listen to what HE says, not to our random solutions when we haven't even heard you sing!